# Qt Creator Designer Issue

Tags: qt, qt-creator

A friend just recommended that I try Qt Creator, so I downloaded it from http://qt.nokia.com/.
When I tried to make a hello world application using the GUI designer, I could not drag any widgets onto the window. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and Qt Creator 2.0.0 on Qt 4.7.0 (64 bit).
I am able to compile projects, but not add widgets to the UI.

Comment: if its persisting even after the re-installation, then log bug to http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com

Comment: Did anyone ever open a bug report on this? Just now seeing this after a fresh intall of Qt4.7.2 on win7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have started with a initial form (File->New...), e.g a Widget or Dialog? 
If not, you can't drag anything to the workspace.